# FROM address incorrect

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

The FROM: address in my emails sent from java don't appear correctly. This is not running in an application server but from a `main()` call:

```
// Get system properties
final Properties properties = System.getProperties();

// Setup mail server
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");

// Get the default Session object.
final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

// Create a default MimeMessage object.
final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

// Set From: header field of the header.
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("support@mydomain.com"));

// Set To: header field of the header.
message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, "you@you.com");

// Set Subject: header field
message.setSubject("Your pants are on fire!");

message.setSentDate(new Date());

// Now set the actual message
message.setText("Take me to the bridge. ow!");

// Send message
Transport.send(message);
```

Here's the raw received email. Two things to note: the linux username under which the java process runs is **mungo**. The linux servername/hostname is **servername**. The domain is **santamaria.com**. These have been changed from their original to protect the guilty.

My question is: why isn't Return-Path **support@mydomain.com** and how can I make it so? Secondarily, how can I add a friendly name? e.g. **Roger Earl <support@mydomain.com>**

```
Delivered-To: you@you.com
Received: by 10.70.125.201 with SMTP id ms9csp51721pdb;
        Sat, 22 Nov 2014 07:38:22 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.140.84.71 with SMTP id k65mr15089869qgd.76.1416670702208;
        Sat, 22 Nov 2014 07:38:22 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <mungo@servername.santamaria.com>
Received: from servername.santamaria.com (servername.santamaria.com. [201.74.27.72])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z90si10522625qgd.46.2014.11.22.07.38.21
        for <you@you.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 22 Nov 2014 07:38:22 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: none (google.com: mungo@servername.santamaria.com does not designate permitted sender hosts) client-ip=201.74.27.72;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=none (google.com: mungo@servername.santamaria.com does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=mungo@servername.santamaria.com
Received: from servername.santamaria.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by servername.santamaria.com (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id sAMFcLkq012340
    for <you@you.com>; Sat, 22 Nov 2014 15:38:21 GMT
From: RogerEarl <mungo@servername.santamaria.com>
Date: Sat, 22 Nov 2014 15:38:21 +0000 (UTC)
To: you@you.com
Message-ID: <1542856295.1.1416670701712.JavaMail.mungo@servername.santamaria.com>
Subject: Your pants are on fire!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Take me to the bridge. ow!
```

**UPDATE**
The working code looks like this:

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.from", "support@mydomain.com");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("support@mydomain.com", "My Friendly Support Name");
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Maybe your smtp server changes the values? If you know how to do it, try sending a mail manually using telnet, and check what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The InternetAddress class includes a constructor that allows you to set a "personal name" along with the email address; read the [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

The Return-Path header is set by the receiving mail server, probably based on the "envelope from" address.  Set the mail.smtp.from property to the address you want to use.

Comment: `message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "Roger Earl"))` and `properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.from", "support@mydomain.com")` did the trick. Thanks!